# batch for opening explorer window in path

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

I've been toggling between commandlines and windows explorer recently and I'd prefer a smoother transition.  So, if I could open an explorer window to the current directory it'd be nice, and easier to shut down a pile of windows.

I tried ex.bat

```
%~d1
cd "%~p1"
start "" "explorer.exe %~dp1"
```

but the result opens to default location.  I feel like I'm close and it's a syntax error , OR it has an interesting solution.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking is following

```
start "explorer ."
```

`.` represents current directory.

Or you could simply use `explorer .` without `start` command

Comment: yes sir that is the one!  I seem to not need a script anymore :)  well I always type exporer and silly things so I did make it shorter (ex) and did [cmd /k "explorer ."]  Cool trick thanks :)